# Spring MVC form select tag , JSP returns error when trying to display the list

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-form

I am trying to display a list of district  in my JSP Using Spring Form Select element. But when the page is loading it throws String is not valid for items error. But I am sure I am setting an arrayList of districts in the controller.  My controller and jsp code is provided below. Can someone please throw some light on it.

```
@GetMapping
public String showWelcomePage(Model model) {

    Register register = new Register();
    CollectionModelEntityModelDistrict collectionModelEntityModelDistrict = districtProviderService.getDistrict();

     List<EntityModelDistrict> districts = collectionModelEntityModelDistrict.getEmbedded().getDistricts();

    if(districts!=null) {
        register.setDistricts(districts);
    }

    model.addAttribute("register",register);
    
    return "login";
    
}
```

**JSP Page**

```
                                    <form:form method="post" action="/register" modelAttribute="register">
                                        <div class="row">

                                            <div class="col-lg-12 no-pdd">
                                                <div class="sn-field">
                                                    <form:select path="districts" items="{$districtsList}" multiple="false"/>

                                                    <i class="la la-dropbox"></i>
                                                    <span><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i></span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            </div>
                                </form:form>
```

**Error**

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Type [java.lang.String] is not valid for option items
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Type [java.lang.String] is not valid for option items
```

Answer (score 0):

path is where the selected value will be set

items are the showed values in the options

you should have in Register a property districts

```
public class Register {
   private String districts; 
   // getters and setters
}
```

in the model you should have districtsList

```
model.addAttribute("districtsList", districtsList);
```

or

```
model.addAttribute("districtsList", regiseter.districtsList);
```

if you are saving value in the Register class